# Could the Valence API be used to handle realtime user account creation and enrollment for large numbers?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Valence allows to do this, but I wondered if there's limitations to trying to automate user account setup and enrollment in this way. We're a relatively small institution with hundreds of enrollments perhaps in a given term scattered over several weeks, so I don't think there'd be a problem with realtime events. But I wondered what the implication might be for a larger university that might have thousands of enrollments updating all the time. There'd be spikes of activity certainly as a term reached official start.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of performance is a complex one, with many inter-dependant factors. I can't comment on the impact of hardware hosting your back-end LMS, but obviously, higher-performance hardware and network deployment will result in higher performance interaction between clients and the LMS.

If your needs are "hundreds of creations scattered over several weeks", that is certainly within comfortable expected performance of a back-end service.

At the moment, each user-creation request must be done separately, and if you want to pre-provide a password for a user, then it takes two calls (you can, in one call, nudge the LMS to send a "password set" email to the new user, but if you want to manually set the password for the user, you have to do that in a separate call after the user record gets created). The individual calls are pretty light-weight, being a simple HTTP POST with response back to provide the created user record's details.

There are roadmapped plans to expand support for batch operations, and batched user-creation is certainly a logical possibility for improvement.